# trabajando arrays en php

Tags: php, array

Tengo el siguiente arreglo llamado $arreglo_alumnos, es una lista de matriculas y nombres de alumnos de un grupo.

```
array(172) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "18B0240137"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "AGUILAR"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "CRUZ"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "ALONDRA"
  [4]=>
  string(9) "GUADALUPE"
  [6]=>
  string(10) "18B0240145"
  [7]=>
  string(5) "ARIAS"
  [8]=>
  string(6) "ROMERO"
  [9]=>
  string(6) "César"
  [10]=>
  string(7) "Adrián"
  [12]=>
  string(10) "18B0240138"
  [13]=>
  string(5) "ARIAS"
  [14]=>
  string(7) "SAGUNDO"
  [15]=>
  string(8) "GHERSSON"
  [16]=>
  string(5) "DAVID"
...
```

Los reacomodo con el siguiente código

```
$posicion_arreglo_final = 0;
        foreach ($arreglo_alumnos as $alumnos){
            if(preg_match('([a-zA-Z].*[0-9]|[0-9].*[a-zA-Z])', $alumnos)){
                $posicion_arreglo_final++;
                $arreglo_final[$posicion_arreglo_final]['matricula'] = $alumnos;
            }else{
                $arreglo_final[$posicion_arreglo_final]['nombre'] .= preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', mb_strtoupper($alumnos)) . ' ';
            }
        }
```

y me genera el siguiente arreglo llamado: $arreglo_final
en resumen lo que hago es recorrer el $arreglo_alumnos y cuando encuentro un string alfanumerico(ME INDICA QUE ES UNA MATRICULA) lo agrego al $arreglo_final en la posición actual en el campo 'matricula' y me paso al siguiente valor del $arreglo_alumnos, si es un string sin números y solo letras lo agrego a la posición anterior pero en el campo 'nombre' y así sucesivamente voy concatenando cada valor del arreglo $arreglo_alumnos para 'generar' el nombre completo del alumno hasta encontrar el siguiente valor alfanumérico y guardarlo en el siguiente espacio del $arreglo_final en el campo 'matricula' para el siguiente alumno.

```
array(34) {
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["matricula"]=>
    string(10) "18B0240137"
    ["nombre"]=>
    string(31) "AGUILAR CRUZ ALONDRA GUADALUPE "
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["matricula"]=>
    string(10) "18B0240145"
    ["nombre"]=>
    string(28) "ARIAS ROMERO CÉSAR ADRIÁN "
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["matricula"]=>
    string(10) "18B0240138"
    ["nombre"]=>
    string(29) "ARIAS SAGUNDO GHERSSON DAVID "
  }
...
```

esto lo ejecuto en un archivo de prueba y me funciona bien. no sé si es lo correcto pero me genera lo que necesito. un array con 2 campos en cada posición. matrícula y nombre completo de cada alumno.
mi problema viene cuando lo paso a mi vista en CodeIgniter 4. Me marca el siguiente error en esta línea de mi código que comparto aquí:

```
ErrorException
Undefined index: nombre

[35] $arreglo_final[$posicion_arreglo_final]['nombre'] .= preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', mb_strtoupper($alumnos)) . ' ';
```

Quisiera saber cómo puedo resolver este problema o si es posible general el array nuevo con la estructura que necesito de alguna otra manera que CI4 no me genere ese error al cargar mi vista.

Agradezco su atención y estoy atento a sus respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

Lo resolví! con el siguiente código:

```
$posicion_arreglo_final = 0;
        foreach ($arreglo_alumnos as $alumnos){
            if(preg_match('([a-zA-Z].*[0-9]|[0-9].*[a-zA-Z])', $alumnos)){
                $posicion_arreglo_final++;
                $arreglo_final[$posicion_arreglo_final] = [
                                                            'matricula' => $alumnos,
                                                            'nombre'  => ''
                ];
            }else{
                $arreglo_final[$posicion_arreglo_final]['nombre'] .= preg_replace('/[0-9]+/', '', mb_strtoupper($alumnos)) . ' ';
            }
        }
```